# How do I "escape" a subscript or superscript in Auctex?

Tags: auctex

Let's say I write a subscript inside a math environment like `\(a_p\)`. Auctex conveniently, and by default creates a pair `{}` and puts the cursor inside of it so I don't have to bother putting them myself to deal with multiple subscripts. However, I wonder if there is there a keymap to escape these `{}` without using the arrow keys. For example, `C-e` puts the cursor outside the math environment, when sometimes I would like to keep writing the formula after done with the subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, of course, alternatives to the arrow keys such as `C-f` and friends.

An alternative is to use the `cdlatex` package (which plays very nicely with `auctex`).  With this loaded, `TAB` calls `cdlatex-tab` which exits `{}` groups and more:

> This function first calls all functions in ‘cdlatex-tab-hook’, which see.
>
> If none of those functions returns t, the command  first tries to expand
> any command keyword before point.
>
> If there is none, it cleans up short subscripts and superscripts at point.
> I.e. it changes a^{2} into a^2, since this is more readable.  This feature
> can be disabled by setting ‘cdlatex-simplify-sub-super-scripts’ to nil.
>
> Then it jumps to the next point in a LaTeX text where one would reasonably
> expect that more input can be put in.
> To do that, the cursor is moved according to the following rules:
>
> The cursor stops...
>
> - before closing brackets if ‘preceding-char’ is any of -({[]})
> - after  closing brackets, but not if ‘following-char’ is any of ({[_^
> - just after $, if the cursor was before that $.
> - at end of non-empty lines
> - at the beginning of empty lines
> - before a SPACE at beginning of line
> - after first of several SPACE

Comment: `C-f` is really what I needed. I might take a look at this function later, but I'm using Tab to trigger snippets right now, and that could cause some issues.

Answer (score 1):

AUCTeX's behavior after `^` and `_` in math mode is controlled by the variable `TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript`:

> `TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript` is a variable defined in ‘tex.el’.
>
> Its value is nil
>
> If non-nil, insert braces after typing `^` and `_` in math mode.

Default value is `nil` which means no braces after `^` and `_`.  As usual, you can press <kbd>C-q ^</kbd> and <kbd>C-q _</kbd> in order to get the literal `^` or `_` without braces where you actually don't need them, e.g., `\(a_p\)`.